# Declaring variable and select table where condition depends on the variable

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How can I convert this (SQL Server) query to PL/SQL (Oracle).
I need to get the data as `SELECT *`

I don't need to print it on console.

```sql
-- This is the MS SQL SERVER QUERY
DECLARE @variable DATE 
SET @variable =  CONVERT(DATE, '09/03/2024', 103)

SELECT * FROM myTable 
WHERE myTable.myDate = @variable
```

```
-- This is the ORACLE Query I tried
DECLARE variable DATE;

BEGIN
  variable := TO_DATE('09/03/2024', 'DD/MM/YYYY');

  SELECT *
  FROM myTable
  WHERE myTable.myDate = variable;
END;
```

Comment: Why do you want to use PL/SQL, and why do you want a variable? Where will the value come from? You might just want a bind variable if the value will come from your application, say, but it’s unclear what you need.

Comment: I guess you check the Oracle docs and find the constructs you need to meet your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use PL/SQL or a variable:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   myTable
WHERE  myTable.myDate = DATE '2024-03-09';
```